# Detecting iframe removed by parent

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a web application that is embedded in an iframe by external sites, of which we have no control over.

Is there a way to detect when the iframe element has been removed from the dom of the parent, in order to perform some cleanup before it's gone? It appears to fire a "visibilitychange" event, but I need to differentiate this between visible, hidden and removed.

Comment: closed means what? visibility change? display changed, deleted from DOM? Basically there is no much you can do other than if they remove it completely.

Comment: Apologies, I mean removed and not closed... have changed the title to reflect this. I want to know when the parent removes the iframe element from the dom.

Comment: onunload would detect it, but that is also the window closing in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was listening for the `"pagehide"` lifecycle event. I already had a handler setup for `"beforeunload"` but for whatever reason, it isn't called in this instance, and my use case was too early for `"unload"`.

Comment: As of August 2023, this unfortunately doesn't work in Firefox if the parent removes the iframe from the page. Can confirm that `pagehide` and `unload` both work fine in Chrome though. It works in Firefox if the iframe itself calls `window.location.reload()`.

Answer (score -2):

You could possibly run a function in the iframe before it closes?
Like, `parent.cleanup()`

Comment: OP is asking how to detect that it is closed..... Your answer does nothing to help answer that question.